# Sorting posts alphabetical that have single digits

Tags: posts, query, title, sort

I have post titles that are like this:

```
Episode 1
Episode 2
Episode 6
Episode 10
Episode 14
```

I try to list posts alphabetically but it ends up showing like this:

```
Episode 1
Episode 10
Episode 14
Episode 2
Episode 6
```

How can i fix this? I don't want to add leading zeros to single digit

Comment: File en [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/173825/edit) to your question and post your code here.

Comment: You need `ORDER BY LENGTH(post_title), post_title`. This has to be passed to `WP_Query` in an `orderby` key, or you have to inject it in `pre_get_posts`. The implementation details **are** WordPress specific, so I will leave this open.